# Elasticsearch 5.1.1 log files are not removed automatically

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5, elasticsearch-2.0

I am using elasticsearch 5.1.1 version. In that, the machine is out of disk space because of elasticsearch logs are occupying 10GB of data. Is there any way to maintain only some 5 days logs.

Comment: Please show the changes you tried in the [log4j2.properties configuration file](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.1/settings.html#logging).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you've looked at this discussion on the Elastic forum regarding someone asking for how to delete logs after a certain period.

[elastic forum](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/delete-logs-in-elasticsearch-after-certain-period/75067)

One of the suggestions was to look at Curator

[Curator](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/curator/5.0/index.html)

which may or may not do what you're after but certainly worth a read of that thread

Comment: Thanks, @c95mbq Gone through the [elastic forum](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/delete-logs-in-elasticsearch-after-certain-period/75067/15) I didn't get the exact solution to this question.